# Show that this relation is an implicit solution of the following differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Differential equation:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$$

Relation:

$$2y^2 \ln{y} - x^2 = 0$$

From this, I end up getting:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x}{2y\ln{y} + y} $$

The missing step would be to put in the form given at the top. How is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiply by $y/y$ first. Note from our relation $2y^2\log y-x^2=0$ that adding $x^2$ to both sides yields $2y^2\log y=x^2$. Substitute for $2y^2\log y$ and you are done.
$$\begin{align*}\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{x}{2y\log y+y}\\&=\frac{xy}{2y^2\log y+y^2}\\&=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\end{align*}$$